# Get the recent ID and insert it to another table in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Please help - I'm creating a simple register from I'm trying to get the `userID` and insert the `UserID` from `User` table into the `Employee` table. I get an error at the line

```
newID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

My `User` table has a primary key `UserID`, the `Employee` table has a column `UserID` as foreign key.

Thank you in advance!

Here is my register.cs

```
 // instantiate 
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon()))
 {
     int newID;

     string query = @"INSERT INTO Users VALUES (@TypeID, @EmployeeId, @Username, @Password, @SecurityQuestion1, @SecurityAnswer1, @SecurityQuestion2, @SecurityAnswer2, @DateModified);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int";

     con.Open();

     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
     {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeID", ddlUserTypes.SelectedValue);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Helper.CreateSHAHash(txtPW.Text));
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityQuestion1", ddlSec1.SelectedValue);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityAnswer1", txtSecAns1.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityQuestion2", ddlSec2.SelectedValue);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityAnswer2", txtSecAns2.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateModified", DateTime.Now);

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         newID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
         con.Close();
     }

     string query2 = @"INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (@FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, @EmployeeNumber, @Gender, @Birthdate, @Birthplace, @Nationality, @CivilStatus, @PermamentAddress, @PresentAddress, @ContactNumber, @Email, @Position, @Department, @Designation, @DateHired, @EmploymentStatus, @TIN, @SSS, @HDMF, @PHIC, @Supervisor, @Remarks, @Photo, @Attachments, @DateModified)";

     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, con))
     {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFN.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", txtMD.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLN.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeNumber", txtEmpNo.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ddlGender.SelectedValue);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthdate", txtbdate.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthplace", txtBP.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", txtNat.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CivilStatus", ddlCIv.SelectedValue);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermamentAddress", txtPermAdd.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PresentAddress", txtPreAdd.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContactNo.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", txtPosi.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", txtDept.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", txtDesig.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateHired", txtdateh.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmploymentStatus", txtEmpl.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIN", txtTin.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSS", txtSSS.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HDMF", txtPhilH.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PHIC", txtPag.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supervisor", txtSuper.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", txtRemarks.Text);

         string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss-") + fuImage.FileName;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", fileName);

         fuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/EmployeeData/Images/" + fileName));
         string attachments = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss-") + fuAttach.FileName;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attachments", attachments);

         fuAttach.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/EmployeeData/Attachments/" + attachments));
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateModified", DateTime.Now);

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: Try removing the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); in the first command.

Comment: remove `con.Close();` after executing the first sql command. There is no need to close the connection as I don't see you opening it before executing the second sql command.

Comment: `SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int` => a parenthesis is missing, this is syntax error. Try `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)`.

Comment: You may also be better off making this one compound query in a [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or a [Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this code gets an error at the line you're saying it happens, since I'd expect an error.at the line before the one mentioned. Here are a variety of tips, too long for a comment. I hope they sort out the problem, and if they dont, then the first point will help you get to the answer.

1. When asking for help about an error, please post the error that you got. This is the *most* important thing about diagnosing an error.
2. The line before the error is `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, which will execute the command, inserting the record. Then you do `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`, which will execute the command again, inserting another record. Remove the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, since you need the identity value back from `ExecuteScalar`.
3. I'm not sure how the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` works (it must do, unless you are mistaken in telling us that it crashes on the next line), since there is a typo in the query, missing the close bracket from the end `SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int`.
4. Please [Can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).
5. There's no need to `Close` the connection (ever), since it's in a `using` block. When it exits that block, the implicit `Dispose` will call `Close`.
6. Consider adding a Transaction. You are doing two separate inserts. If the second one fails, you will be left with the first record in the database. If you use a transaction around both commands, then either they both get in, or neither get in.
7. You're passing `@DateModified` the value `DateTime.Now`, which is a 'Local' time (look at the `Kind` property). When you read the value back from SQL, unless you call SpecifyKind, it won't be a local time, leading to discrepancies. Safer to always store and read the value as UTC (by using `DateTime.UtcNow` here, and SpecifyKind UTC when you read it) or switch to using DateTimeOffset.